LNK2019 Error during compilation of Win32 Program
Just trying to run a simple Win32 program (From Handmade Hero Series by Casey Muratori)
Its not a Visual Studio Project. Its just a cpp file with Visual studio C compiler in command line.
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowCallback(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam){
    
    LRESULT Result = 0;

    return Result;

}

int CALLBACK WinMain (HINSTANCE Instance, HINSTANCE PrevInstance, LPSTR CommandLine, int ShowCode){
    
    WNDCLASS WindowClass = {};
    
    WindowClass.style = CS_OWNDC|CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowCallback;
    WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "HandmadeHeroWindowClass";

    if(RegisterClass(&WindowClass)){
        HWND WindowHandle = {};
    } else {

        }

    return 0;
}

Command Line:
W:\src>cl -Zi handmade.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.39.33521 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

handmade.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.39.33521.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:handmade.exe
/debug
handmade.obj
handmade.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassA referenced in function WinMain
handmade.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tried replacing RegisterClass with RegisterClassA RegisterClassW RegisterClassEx, but that didn't work. Win32 Docs have Visual Studio specific answers. Help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix - you need to learn the different steps of C++ program preprocessing,  compilation and linking.

You compile handmade.cpp, why do you tag C?

Because its only c code in the file

No, it contains lines that are invalid in C. I've tried your code and got errors, your tags lie.

Guessing and trials do not work in IT. RTM and you find the answer.

The Windows documentation isn't Visual Studio specific. If you look up the function you're using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassa you can scroll to the bottom and see what library you need to link with.

You miss linking with windows libraries. That why error LNK2019 come.
Use this command:
cl handmade.cpp user32.lib

This link user32.lib with your code and will fix the problem.
